# Contact form sends, refreshes page and form, BUT then doesn't send anything after Submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

I'm very new to coding, so feel free to treat me like an idiot. I have managed to create a modal contact form with bootstrap 3. Thing works beautifully the first time round, it pops up and then sends the information to my e-mail. I then have a refresh function so after submitting it returns to the same page and when the link is again pressed the modal pops back up clear of any previously entered info. Again this is working. However when you submit this time I get nothing in my email.

Now I have a theory that what is happening is the variables are clearing after the first submit so php code won't work the second time. But that's just a theory I'm not very adept at php at all.

So below is modal contact form script and the php I'm using.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Ambedo'; 
        $to = 'charlieboman@live.com.au'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Ambedo ';

        $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
            (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from));
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Ambedo/Contact</title>

    <link href="../bootstrap-3.3-2.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="Ambedo_Contact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://use.typekit.net/uvm0tgt.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="messages">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="message-content">
                <a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal"><img class="e-mail" src="Untitled-1.jpg"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role
            "form" method="post" action="Ambedo_Contact.php" onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Please Get In Touch!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="contact-message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap-3.3-2.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does `!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage` come from?

Comment: You may use if(!$name & .......

Comment: rather than onsubmit use header("Location:formfile.php") in your action file...

Comment: the !$errName etc is left over from some earlier code, I've deleted it now I've noticed it still there.

Comment: @Akki tried your suggestion, I put action="location:formfile.php". After I pressed submit all I got was was safari doesn't recognise a url that starts with location. Might be totally misunderstanding your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you submit the form to the same page and if you want to clear the form once you submit the form then remove the following line from your form and submit the data to the same page.

```
onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)"
```

If you submit the form to any other php page and if you want to clear the form once you submit the form add the following line after "mail()" function

```
header('Location: <http://www.yoursite.com>');
```

If you submit the form to any php page and you don't want to clear the form once you submit the form then use ajax.

```
$(document).rady(function(){
$("form").submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "your_php_file.php",
        data:$('form').serialize(),
        dataType:'html',
        success: function(result){
             alert(result);
        }
    });
});});
```

You can get the form data in the php file and you can process. What ever you "echo" in the php file will be shown on the screen in alert box.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing some more details, it's hard to know exactly what's going on.

However, you should do some basic error-checking in your PHP-code, such as checking that the variables is actually set and that the `mail()` function actually returns true (if you read the [PHP `mail()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), it'll tell you that `mail()` will return a Boolean (true/false). You'll also notice that the 4th parameter is a *header*).

I'll show you an example of how you *could* do it (there are many ways), which mainly focuses that you should check for errors.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'], $_POST['human'])) {
        // Checks if the variables can be set, so that we don't get undefined index errors
        // You could also do other forms of error-checking here
        // Such as validating the email-address, names and such
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);

        $errorOccured = false; // No errors
    } else {
        $errorOccured = true; // Some of the variables can't be set - this is an error
    }

    $to = 'charlieboman@live.com.au'; // The address we're sending the form to
    $subject = 'Message from Ambedo '; // Subject of the message

    // Headers in the email goes here...
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8<br />";
    $headers .= "From: Ambedo <contactform@yourwebsite.com> <br />";
    $headers .= "To: Ambedo <$to> \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$name."  <".$email.">" . "\r\n";

    // Body of the email: the contents that will be shown
    $body = "From: $name\n";
    $body .= "E-Mail: $email\n";
    $body .= "Message:\n $message";

    if (!$errorOccured) { // If we had no error, we can proceed
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { // If mail is sent, all is good!
            // Message was sent (mail returned true)!
        } else {
            // An error occurred sending the email, could be for various reasons...
            // Display error message here
        }
    } else { // $errorOccured == true, so something bad happened...
        // Not all variables were set, so email couldn't be sent
        // Deal with it here, display error message and show the form again
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your complete code would be something like :

```
        $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        if ($name!='' && $email!='' && $message!='' ) {
            if(mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)){
               header('Location:Ambedo_Contact.php');
            }
         }
    } 
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Ambedo/Contact</title>

<link href="../bootstrap-3.3-2.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Ambedo_Contact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://use.typekit.net/uvm0tgt.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div class="messages">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="message-content">
            <a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal"><img class="e-mail" src="Untitled-1.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role
        "form" method="post" >
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h1>Please Get In Touch!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap-3.3-2.5-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that i've removed onsubmit event and redirected current page to the same page after mailing the detail.